# Working Java project and i keep getting errors im stuck

Tags: java

Here's the question for the project.

Find solutions for your homework

Search
home / study / engineering / computer science / computer science questions and answers / in java code a program that tabulates contributions collected by an organization. the organization ...
Your question has been answered
Let us know if you got a helpful answer. Rate this answer
Question: In Java code a program that tabulates contributions collected by an organization. The organization...
In Java code a program that tabulates contributions collected by an organization. The organization wishes to accept contributions until a total of $10,000,000 is met. Once this total is hit, no further contributions should be accepted. The organization wants the program to read data from an input file (input.in). The following data should be written to a file called results.out

a.The total number of contributions needed to meet the goal of 10 million dollars

b.The amount of the largest and smallest contribution accepted

c.The average contribution size

d.The final total of the contributions accepted

3.Implement (code) and test your program with a variety of input data. It is helpful to set a smaller contribution goal when testing your program. Consider both the scenario where the input file does not contain enough contributions to meet the goal and the scenario where the input file contains more data than needed. The output file should match the formatting shown in the example:

The maximum contribution received was $53,246.00.

The minimum contribution received was $7.00.

The average contribution amount was $4, 982.58.

A total of $10,000,34.00 was collected.

Here's my code:

```java
public class Contribution {

    public void fileOperation(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
        double max_contro = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double min_contro = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int total = 0;
        int goal = 1000;
        double current = 0.0;

//         Reading from the file
        try {
            File file = new File(inputFile);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                double amt = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
                current += amt;
                total++;
                if (amt < min_contro) {
                    min_contro = amt;
                }
                if (amt > max_contro) {
                    max_contro = amt;
                }
                if (current > goal) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error processing the file!");
        }

        double average_contro = Math.round((double) current / total);
//         Writing to the file
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile, true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            out.write("It took " + total
                    + " contributions to reach the goal.\nThe maximum contribution"
                    + " received was $" + max_contro + ".\nThe minimum contribution"
                    + " received was $" + min_contro + "\nThe average contribution amount was $"
                    + average_contro + ".\nA total of $" + current + " was collected.");
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error processing the file!");
        }
    }

//     Driver method to test the code
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputFile = "input.in";
        String outputFile = "output.out";

        Contribution obj = new Contribution();
        obj.fileOperation(inputFile, outputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you wrote *all* of this and are just getting errors now, then you need to compile more often so that things don't sneak up on you. If you found this code on the Internet and want us to explain why it's not working, then that's called academic dishonesty and you need to not do that. Regardless, take a look at the error and see what it's telling you. Then look at your teacher's example Java code and see if there's something basic they do that you don't. Something maybe at the top of the file.

Comment: Code is working perfectly fine see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is working fine:
you just need to import below :

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
```

your whole and correct code will be:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Contribution {


    public void fileOperation(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
        double max_contro = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double min_contro = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        int total = 0;
        int goal = 1000;
        double current = 0.0;

//          Reading from the file
        try {
            File file = new File(inputFile);
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {

                double amt = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
                current += amt;
                total++;
                if (amt < min_contro) {
                    min_contro = amt;
                }
                if (amt > max_contro) {
                    max_contro = amt;
                }
                if (current > goal) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error processing the file!");
        }

        double average_contro = Math.round((double) current / total);
//          Writing to the file
        try {
            FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile, true);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
            out.write("It took " + total + " contributions to reach the goal.\nThe maximum contribution"
                    + " received was $" + max_contro + ".\nThe minimum contribution"
                    + " received was $" + min_contro + "\nThe average contribution amount was $"
                    + average_contro + ".\nA total of $" + current + " was collected.");
            out.newLine();
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error processing the file!");
        }

    }

    //      Driver method to test the code
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String inputFile = "input.in";
        String outputFile = "output.out";

        Contribution obj = new Contribution();
        obj.fileOperation(inputFile, outputFile);

    }
}
```

**Output**:
[image: output image]

in output window lastly it goes to catch block and prints the catch block statement.